# Undefined array key when insert many-to-one relation: Symfony & Doctrine

Tags: php-8.1, symfony5.4

I have table cart & cart_option.

### Cart

- id (PK)
- cart_number
- total

### Cart_option

- id (PK)
- cart_number (FK)

Here is my entity for `CartOption`

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cart::class, inversedBy: 'cartItems')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?Cart $cartNumber;
```

Now when I try to insert, I am getting this error: `An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cart_number_id' in 'field list'`

This is the code, I have tried

```
$cart = $this->entityManager
                     ->getRepository(Cart::class)
                     ->findOneBy(['cartNumber' => $cartNumber]);

$option = new CartOption();
$option->setCartNumber($cart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the column name. Indeed, you do not follow the standard conventions of Doctrine.

See this [doc](https://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

You should declare like this

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cart::class, inversedBy: 'cartItems')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_number", referencedColumnName="cart_number", nullable: false)]
private ?Cart $cartNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeppi now I am getting `Warning: Undefined array key "cartNumber"`